# Dangers from intermittent phase issues

Tags: electrical, appliances

while experiencing a electrical phase issue (loose/failing service connection causing brief outages on one phase), what dangers is there to things plugged in?  Any actions to take to either eliminate or reduce them?

I have already taken the time to unplug the major electronic items, and I'm sure other things will take the brief outages well enough, but what about 240v appliances and things like the fridge and freezer?

[Ohio, United States]

Answer (score 1):

You may not have trouble with your appliances, but the intermittent connection could be generating an enormous amount of heat and spark an electrical fire. If the intermittent connection is on the utility pole then you probably don't need to feel responsible; if it's in your breaker box or in your wall then you should be **extremely** concerned.

As a rule of thumb, a loose connection where your lights are either completely on or completely off isn't a concern; it's the times when your lights are **half** on where that connection can be dissipating an enormous amount of energy. Worst case, the connection could be dissipating on the order of one quarter of the full usual load, so with a 3400W electric dryer you could have almost a kilowatt of power heating up that connection. Could get entertaining fast.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only losing one leg of the service then nothing more than irritation will occur.

Your AC unit actually uses a single relay to turn it on and off essentially making and breaking one leg of the 240 volts when it cycles. All other 240 volt equipment will just shut off along with all of the 120 volt equipment on that leg. Irritating but not harmful.

Notice I call them legs instead of phases to reduce confusion. Residential services are single phase with two legs that are each 120 volts to ground and 240 volts between them. So, there is really only one phase to lose.

Call your utility and register a complaint if it continues.

Good luck!

Comment: That's not necessarily true.  While *some* condensing units use a single pole contactor, some actually use double pole contactors.

Answer (score 0):

I had it a few times for 2-weeks while the utility called everyone in the neighborhood crazy. I had no after-effect issues with big or small stuff & did as you did after the fact. But, I also had a lot of outages back then so I was surge protected on the lightweight electronics already. Everything on the 1-phase worked fine & I ran extension cords to hook things up to different circuits as needed.